# Calling Kotlin function with parameter as sealed class from java

Tags: java, kotlin, sealed-class

My Kotlin class `TimeUtils` has a sealed class declared as:

```
sealed class TimeUnit {
    object Second : TimeUnit()
    object Minute : TimeUnit()

fun setTimeOut(timeout : TimeUnit) {
    // TODO something
}
```

My Java class is calling `setTimeOut` method like:

```
TimeUtils obj = new TimeUtils();
if (some condition) {
    obj.setTimeOut(TimeUtils.TimeUnit.Minute);   // ERROR
} else if (some other condition) {
    obj.setTimeOut(TimeUtils.TimeUnit.Second);   // ERROR
}
```

I am getting error at above 2 lines stating `expression required`. 
Can anyone help how can I solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should invoke the function as following:

```
obj.setTimeOut(TimeUtils.TimeUnit.Minute.INSTANCE);
```

It's because `object Minute` will be compiled to the following Java code:

```
public final class Minute {
   public static final Minute INSTANCE;

   private Minute() {
   }

   static {
      Minute var0 = new Minute();
      INSTANCE = var0;
   }
}
```